# SFTP failed From Rocky Linux 9.2 OS server "Unable to negotiate with 10.7.4.5 port 22: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss"

Tags: linux

I am unable to do sftp From Rocky Linux 9.2 OS server. Getting error  "Unable to negotiate with 10.7.4.5 port 22: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss"

Error snap :

root@edna1-dc21 ~]# sftp mrs@10.7.4.5
Unable to negotiate with 10.7.4.5 port 22: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
Connection closed.
Connection closed

Answer (score 0):

The `sshd` in the 10.7.4.5 server is using older SHA1-based host key algorithms that the SSH client in your `edna1-dc21` system no longer wants to use by default.

You could add a `Host` block in your `~/.ssh/config` file on `edna1-dc21` like this:

```
Host 10.7.4.5
  HostKeyAlgorithms ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
```

Alternatively, you can do it by adding a command line option too:

```
sftp -oHostKeyAlgorithms=ssh-rsa,ssh-dss mrs@10.7.4.5
```

This will tell the new SSH client to accept those old deprecated host key algorithms for as long as they are still supported.

If the `sshd` in the remote server is very old, after making this change you might get another error message:

```
... no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: <something>.
```

That would indicate you'll need to add one more option, `KexAlgorithms <something>` in the `~/.ssh/config` or `-oKexAlgorithms=<something>` on the command line.